# Display query results based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

More of a conceptual question. I have a query that calculates a sum of some values and checks it against a template value X, something like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(...),
    X,
    SUM(...) - X AS delta
FROM
...
```

Now the query by itself works fine. The problem is that I need it to only display some results if the `delta` variable is non-zero, meaning there is a difference between the calculated sum and template X. If `delta` is zero, I need it to display nothing.

Is this possible to achieve in SQL? If yes, how would I go about it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an aggregation query.  Many, if not most, databases support column aliases in the `having` clause:

```
select . . .
from . . .
group by . . .
having delta <> 0;
```

For those that don't, it is probably simplest to repeat the expressions:

```
having sum( . . . ) <> X
```

You can also put the query into a CTE or subquery, and then use `where` on the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support column alias in the `HAVING` clause. so in oracle, You must have to repeat the aggregation in the `HAVING` clause.

See this:

```
SQL> SELECT MAX(COL1) AS RES,
  2         COL2
  3    FROM (select 1 as col1, 1 as col2 from dual
  4          union all
  5          select 10 as col1, 2 as col2 from dual)
  6   GROUP BY COL2
  7  HAVING RES > 5;
HAVING RES > 5
       *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "RES": invalid identifier


SQL> SELECT MAX(COL1) AS RES,
  2         COL2
  3    FROM (select 1 as col1, 1 as col2 from dual
  4          union all
  5          select 10 as col1, 2 as col2 from dual)
  6   GROUP BY COL2
  7  HAVING MAX(COL1) > 5;

       RES       COL2
---------- ----------
        10          2

SQL>
```